Array to get 7 inputs from user - KOTLIN
I need to make an app that allows the user to enter their screen time for the morning and afternoon along with the date their putting in the entry and notes of the day. They must enter the dates and screentimes like this over the course of a week only - 7 days.... how do i go about them storing it in arrays to call it on the next screen where i must display the average screen time for the week.
I tried edit texts but it looks way too messy and seems overcomplicating..
i want to try list views too but have no idea how.

It seems that the app needs to persist the entered data somewhere so it can be restored when the app was closed and reopened. What persistence framework do you use? A DataStore? A Room database? Something else? The answer to your question will heavily depend on that. Please [edit] and clarify. Also you need to provide the data structure you use to store the entered data.

My idea is to making array of pairs which has first and second part of one index, You can store morning screen time in first part of pair and screen time of afternoon at second part of an array
for first day It will store to 0th index and for second day it stores in 1st index for this one you can also use modulo by 7 method and also If you want to store date then It is not good idea to get date from user.
The Calendar class provides current date/time.
for storing date along with screen time use array of pair of pair and integer
ex. Array<Pair<String,Pair<Integer,Integer>>> , here string is concatenation of day, month, year getting from calender class.

"The Calendar class provides current date/time." -> if you mean java.util.Calendar, please avoid using that class. It is old and problematic and has been replaced by classes in the java.time package a long time ago.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
